# Compression ratio for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compression

Given a numpy array, is there a script that can be written, purely in python, that returns its compression ratio?

This is a very simple, specific problem that I can't seem to come up with a good solution for without manually making use of the file system.

Note that making use of the compressed file itself is irrelevant to this problem. The answer need only pertain to the compression ratio value.

Comment: You mean a numpy array? Or a numpy file? Are we talking about file size? or memory size?

Comment: The question seems too vague.  For example, suppose `a = np.array([1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5])`.  Does it even make sense to ask for the "compression ratio" of `a`?  If you have something more specific in mind, please update the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'm using numpy arrays of of shape (28 x 28 x 3), they represent images. I don't think that matters though - `np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])` is more compressible than `np.array([1, 2, 0, 3, 
 4, 0, 5])` for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I suppose I'm referring to a .npy file, unless there is a way to create compressed python objects in memory and directly gauge how much memory they take up compared to the original array.

Comment: There are many compression algorithms; the comression ratio will depend on the algorithm.  It sounds like you want to know how much the array will be compressed when it is written to a compressed npz file, without actually creating the file.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The compression ratio will be compared across many samples and so the relative ratio is all that matters really. Not sure if the compression algorithm would make a difference (it would be consistent across all samples). What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As numPy uses c, I don't think a pure python solution is possible but you can avoid the file system using [stringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html). Using numpy built in functions `np.savez_compression` we can then compare the resulting sizes to `np.savez`,

```
import StringIO

def get_compression_ratio(a):

    uncompressed = StringIO.StringIO()
    compressed = StringIO.StringIO()
    np.savez_compressed(compressed, a)
    np.savez(uncompressed, a)

    return uncompressed.len/float(compressed.len)

a = np.zeros([1000,1000])
a[23,60] = 1.
b = np.random.random([1000,1000])

print("one number = ", get_compression_ratio(a), 
      "random = ", get_compression_ratio(b))
```

with result,

```
('one number = ', 1001.0255255255255, 'random = ', 1.0604228730260878)
```

As the random numbers are incompressible, this makes some sense but the array with one non-zero value should be better. The result relies on the algorithm in `savez_compression` being efficient/correct.